Wall in medical center becomes a portal to bring injured through
I saw a few minutes of this about twenty years ago on television; probably a movie, but possibly a show.
The specific scene I can recall is a medical emergency where a wall in a medical center becomes a portal to another location and they bring someone injured through.
I believe the complex was underground in a desert, and large doors could be opened to expose a ramp to allow vehicles to enter/exit.

Are you thinking of Island City (1994)? It was a pilot for a science fiction show and the opening credits show everything you just described - medical centre portal and ramps into a desert city. The premise was a panacea drug eventually caused insanity in most of the world's population, driving the sane people into walled off, secure cities. Of course, maybe it was just the 90's hair that drove everyone insane...

Yes, this is it. Thank you!

You might possibly be describing Stargate, which was both a movie, and a spinoff show (and another spinoff show).
It contains portals, deserts, and ramps to the portal to allow vehicles.

No, the ramp was to the facility, not to the portal. I think the portal was more like the nanowall used in the Doom movie. link

@Omni Did you check the movie and/or TV series out? There's a ton of different portals and locations (at least throughout the series,) so it could still be the movie/show you're looking for

@Tom Yes, I have seen the movie and all episodes; the timeframe is wrong though. The movie may have been released when I saw this, but it would have been too soon for it to have been broadcast OTA I think.
